# Visual Studio Code Live Share Autocompletion Very Delayed

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

I'm working with a friend on a project using the Visual Studio Code Live Share Extension and I've been running into some issues...

I've come to realise that the host(the person hosting the live share session) gets autocompletions however the person who is not the host gets autocompletions however, they are painfully slow (around 15 seconds per word).

I've not extensively used Visual Studio Code Live Share however I didn't tamper with any existing settings and I've had the same issue on my other machines too. Does anyone know why this is happening and if this is supposed to happen? My friend also reports this problem when we code and I am the host so I'm not sure what to do right now to fix the completions taking ages to arrive. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Note: We both have a stable internet connection and our pc's are very capable machines so i don't think it should be an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Try customizing your settings configuration.
Make sure that these settings are there:

Controls if suggestions should automatically show up while typing

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": false,
  "strings": false
},
```

Try changing this setting and check if it makes a difference.

```
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
```